# trying to achieve parallel tests execution using cucumber JVM(BDD) and testng (factory implementation)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, bdd, thread-local, cucumber-jvm

Using thread local concept of java to instantiate the web driver instance for multiple nodes, how could we achieve parallel test execution using cucumber JVM(BDD) + testing factory implementation..

Any suggestions would be appreciated..:)

Comment: Show us what you have got so far?